# PHP Contact Form 403 Error

Tags: php, html

In the process of setting up a website for myself, i've hit a bit of a road block with the PHP contact form. I believe it is coded correctly, but whenever I upload it to my site and try to use the contact form I get "Page is forbidden 403". I'm using Hostinger by the way, i've set the permissions of my public_html file to 755. Not sure what the problem could be. Included is my code, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Contact code of the HTML from the index:

```html
<div class="row stay-behind" id="contact">
  <h4 class="right-name">Contact</h4>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 feature-image"><img alt="VX1K" height="510" src="images/ux/004.jpg" width="374"> <img alt="VX1K" class="mobile-only" src="images/ux/mobile/004.jpg"></div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6 main">
    <h3 class="title">Contact</h3>
    <form class="contact-form" id="contactForm" novalidate method="post" action="public_html/mail/contact_me.php">
      <div id="form-alert"></div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" type="name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" type="email">
      </div>
      <textarea class="form-control" id="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea> <input class="btn btn-block btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" name="submit" type="submit" value="Send">
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-1"></div>
```

Code from the PHP file.

```
<?php

function Validate()
    {

    // Check for empty fields

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['message']) || !filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
        {
        return false;
        }
      else return true;
    }

function SendEmail($to = 'noreply@vx1k.com')
    {
    if (Validate() == true)
        {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email_address = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        // Create the email and send the message

        $email_subject = "Website Contact Form:  $name";
        $email_body = "You have received a new message from your website contact form.\n\n" . "Here are the        
                details:\n\nName: $name\n\nEmail: $email_address\n\nMessage:\n$message";
        $headers = "From: noreply@vx1k.com\n";
        $headers.= "Reply-To: $email_address";

        // Send true on successful send.
        // Send false if failed

        return (mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body, $headers)) ? true : false;
        }
      else

    // Invalid inputs

    return 'err';
    }

// Apply function(s). You will get true, false, or err

$send = SendEmail();

// On return, you can echo any result

if ($send == 'err') echo 'Invalid Fields.';
elseif ($send == false) echo 'An Error Occurred.';
  else echo 'Email Sent Successfully.';
?>
```

Comment: `403 Forbidden` suggests a server configuration problem, it's not coming from the script.

Comment: Check you .htaccess

Comment: @SumanDey I actually don't have an htaccess file, if I were to create one, any suggestion of what to enter in there?

Comment: what name in your page?

Comment: @SumanDey Sorry I don't understand, but I think you are asking for the name of my files? index.html and my other file is contact_me.php and it's located in public_html/mail/contact_me.php

Comment: What is your website name

Comment: @SumanDey Oh sorry!! :) It's vx1k.com

Comment: drop the `public_html` that part is not part of the web address.

Comment: I' see you use publice_html delete them use only mail/file.php

Comment: @Luke Thanks! I no longer get the 403 error, but I know get a message that says "Invalid Fields". Any idea why my code could be causing that?

Comment: @SumanDey Thanks! I no longer get the 403 error, but I know get a message that says "Invalid Fields". Any idea why my code could be causing that?

Comment: Ok. Can i see your php code?

Comment: @SumanDey It is in my post. It's the second box down titled "Code from the PHP file."

Comment: Add name="message" field

Comment: @SumanDey Sorry I am a SUPER big noob, where should I add that in? c:

Comment: `<textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" placeholder="Message" rows="3"></textarea>` add this

Comment: @SumanDey HOLY SHIT!! It worked!!! Thanks so much man!!! It works and I got the email but when it sends it still says "Invalid Fields", yet the email sent xD

Comment: do you use teamviwer

Comment: @SumanDey No, sorry! I don't teamviewer with people I don't know very well but thank you very much for your help man! I really appreciate it!! :D

Comment: ok i check it..